# chained query on google firestore

Tags: database, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, schema

Data for one of our application use case is stored in firestore in below format:

```
"Collection" : "ROOT_COLLECTION"
     "Documents" : MAIN_ID_1 : attribute : is_enabled:1
                               "subcollection": "Sessions"
                                               Documents : Session_1: attribute: is_merged:false
                                                           Session_2: attribute: is_merged:true
                                                           Session_3: attribute: is_merged:false
                   MAIN_ID_2 : attribute : is_enabled:2
                               "subcollection": "Sessions"
                                               Documents : Session_4: attribute: is_merged:false
                                                           Session_5: attribute: is_merged:true
                                                           Session_6: attribute: is_merged:true
                   MAIN_ID_3 : attribute : is_enabled:1
                               "subcollection": "Sessions"
                                               Documents : Session_7: attribute: is_merged:true
                                                           Session_8: attribute: is_merged:true
                                                           Session_9: attribute: is_merged:true
                   MAIN_ID_4 : attribute : is_enabled:1
                               "subcollection": "Sessions"
                                               Documents : Session_10: attribute: is_merged:false
                                                           Session_11: attribute: is_merged:false
                                                           
                   ......
```

Here we want to find all last level sessions from root collection documents where is_enabled is true and sessions where is_merged is false in a single query, so that we can put listener on top of all retrieved sessions.

**Query** : is_enabled on documents in root collection : 1
is_merged on documents in session collection : false

**Result** should be session documents:
Session1,Session3,Session7,Session8,Session9

How can achieve this using single chained/combined query from firestore and listener on it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries can only execute against a single collection, or against collections of the same name. Queries can only consider data in the documents they return, they have no way to look at data in other documents.

Combined, these two limits means that your use-case cannot be implemented as a single query on your current data model.

Your options are to:

- either query the top-level documents first for documents with the right value for `is_enabled`, and then loop over the results, and query their `sessions` for the documents matching `is_merged:false`.
- or you can duplicate the data from `is_enabled` into each underlying `sessions` document, and perform the query with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) across all `sessions` subcollections.

Neither if these is pertinently better than the other. As usual when dealing with NoSQL databases, you're trading off increased data storage and a more complex data model for a faster and simpler query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank
We were also thinking in the direction you shared.
Just wanted an expert opinion to check if still there is some option to execute this with the schema we have.
Your feedback will help us take informed decision.

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to make this work with this structure. It would not be easy and there is a much better way of doing it.

You seem to have fallen into the trap of using Firestore like a relational database instead of a document store.

If you want to keep this structure then I would suggest adding a cloud function or something that would update the top level documents when a session in a subcollection is updated. This way you can put a value like `contains_unmerged_session: Bool` or something in it. That feels hacky though.

A possible better way would be to have a top level collection of `sessions` and then in each session store a reference to the parent in the session document. It's hard to tell from your question how that relationship works but that's probably what I would do.

The best approach when doing anything in Firestore is to structure your data how you want to get it on the client. If the structure makes it difficult to query... change the structure.

Comment: Very valid suggestions Fogmeister, thanks for answering.